# Magento2 with nginix + ssl + varnish admin redirect loop issue

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, nginx, ssl, varnish

everything working fine, but when I enable secure admin (ssl) it gives redirect loop issue. I am not able to use admin pannel also cross origin issue for front ens static content.

I am using ssl over nginx + varnish.

I tried so many things (even may stackexchange answers) but no luck. can someone help me to tackle this issue.

Nginx configuration (magento2 nginx sample config included).

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server   unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
  server {
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com 1xx.xx.xx.xxx; #private Ip included
    listen 8080;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/mysiteconf;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer; # or production

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  #mujassam
        #fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    include /var/www/html/mydomain/nginx.conf.sample;
  }
server {

      # listen 443 ssl;

      #added by mujassam
      listen 443 ssl http2; #m ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and
      implied listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
      server_name www.mydomain.com;

      ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/www_mydomain_com.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/www_mydomain_com.key;
      ssl_protocols              TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      #mujassam
       #  fastcgi_param   HTTPS               on;
       # fastcgi_param   HTTP_SCHEME         https;
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
      ###
      ssl_ciphers               'AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH:!aNULL';
      ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
      ssl_session_timeout 24h;
      keepalive_timeout 300s;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded "1";
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    #mujassam added
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    #proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
    #proxy_hide_header Via;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }
}
```

Hope Some body can help.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and someone tells me to set the base url with **https**.

Set to **NO** for `Use Secure URLs on Storefront` AND `Use Secure URLs in Admin`.

If you can't access to admin panel, you could do this with :

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="https://yourdomain.com"

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Issue: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS - redirected you too many times**

This issue is related cookie domain name.

For ex: if you already installed Magento 2 in **www.example.com**, and now you change magento base path to sub domain path like **www.subdomain.example.com** means, then you need to update your cookie domain entry inside of **core_config_data** table. You cannot access magento 2 backend so you can use following query to check record exist else use insert query.

```
SELECT * FROM  `core_config_data` WHERE  `path` REGEXP  'cookie_domain'
```

if record exit then update **subdomain.example.com** to the value column.

else

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES ('default', 0, 'web/cookie/cookie_domain', 'subdomain.example.com');
```

Then flush cache using command **php bin/magento cache:flush**

Refresh magento 2 admin, now you can access admin. try this. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for providing a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here to hopefully save others some time.

I had everything configured correctly in regards to Varnish but was setting up a new environment that also utilized Redis for session and backend cache.

Double check the projects var/log derectory for redis errors. In my case it was unable to connect to the redis server and somehow that routed the traffic back to varnish and created a redirect loop.